# cant change wordpress sidebar items

Tags: wordpress, sidebar, woocommerce

I have a wordpress site with a sidebar that is themed from a theme I downloaded.

In Appearance > Menus I have created a new menu then I set the side bar menu drop down list to the newly created menu, however when you go to the website it makes no difference.. the old menu is still there...

[image]

So I looked at the code  editor from the theme and I cannot figure out how to change it so it works from my newly created menu, I am hoping someone might be able to help me out.. this is the sidebar.php code and the sidebar-init.php

sidebar-init.php

```
<?php
function elegance_widgets_init() {
    // Header Widget
    // Location: right after the navigation
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'                  => 'Header',
        'id'                        => 'header-sidebar',
        'description'   => __( 'Located at the top of pages.'),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));
    // Sidebar Widget
    // Location: the sidebar
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'                  => 'Sidebar',
        'id'                        => 'main-sidebar',
        'description'   => __( 'Located at the right side of pages.'),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));
    // Contact Form Widget
    // Location: Contacts page
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'                  => 'Contact Form',
        'id'                        => 'contact_form',
        'description'   => __( 'Located at the left side of Contacts page.'),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));
    // Address Widget
    // Location: Contacts page
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'                  => 'Address',
        'id'                        => 'address',
        'description'   => __( 'Located at the right side of Contacts page.'),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));
    // Footer Widget Area
    // Location: at the top of the footer, above the copyright
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'                  => 'First footer widget area',
        'id'                        => 'first-footer-widget-area',
        'description'   => __( 'Located at the bottom of pages.'),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-area">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h4>',
        'after_title' => '</h4>',
    ));
    // Footer Widget Area
    // Location: at the top of the footer, above the copyright
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'                  => 'Second footer widget area',
        'id'                        => 'second-footer-widget-area',
        'description'   => __( 'Located at the bottom of pages.'),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-area">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h4>',
        'after_title' => '</h4>',
    ));
    // Footer Widget Area
    // Location: at the top of the footer, above the copyright
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'                  => 'Third footer widget area',
        'id'                        => 'third-footer-widget-area',
        'description'   => __( 'Located at the bottom of pages.'),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-area">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h4>',
        'after_title' => '</h4>',
    ));
    // Footer Widget Area
    // Location: at the top of the footer, above the copyright
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'                  => 'Fourth footer widget area',
        'id'                        => 'fourth-footer-widget-area',
        'description'   => __( 'Located at the bottom of pages.'),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-area">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h4>',
        'after_title' => '</h4>',
    ));

}
/** Register sidebars by running elegance_widgets_init() on the widgets_init hook. */
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'elegance_widgets_init' );
?>
```

sidebar.php

```
<aside id="sidebar" class="grid_6 omega">
    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'Sidebar' )) : ?>

        <div id="sidebar-nav" class="widget menu">
            <h3>Navigation</h3>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Sidebar Menu' )); ?> <!-- editable within the Wordpress backend -->
        </div>


    <?php endif; ?>
</aside><!--sidebar-->
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="sidebar-nav" class="widget menu">
            <h3>Navigation</h3>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Catalogue' )); ?> <!-- editable within the Wordpress backend -->
</div>
```

Simply change the value in wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => '**Catalogue**')); that will call your menu entitled 'Catalogue', the theme states that you can change the selected menu from the backend

Comment: Also, make sure that under appearence->widgets->sidebar make sure this is empty, and no widgets are in that area, or your menu wont show!..

Comment: okay this worked at getting the entries to change!! which I am excited about cause its taken me ages to get any where on this.. but it had changed the style of the menu.. I will add pictured for before and after to my question so you have a better idea.

Comment: actually I cannot seem to get it back now... :( gonna keep trying will let you know how I go.. but do you know why I am loosing my style when I use this code.

Comment: I can't see any reason as to why it would lose its style to be honest, maybe you can revert it back to how it was, inspect the elements and see what has changed and what hasn't? Could be the other menu had some classes assigned to it